# load external web pages in web application

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to create a angularjs web application that will allow to inspect elements of external web pages. I am not able to load other sites because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Can angularjs solve this? I have seen many sites doing this. How this is usually done?

Also I would like to know how to make an inspector like dev-tools in angularjs? Get clicked element details which is loaded in the div.

tried

$('#div').load()

$.ajax({..., crossDomain:true, ...

XMLHttpRequest, XDomainRequest

Comment: This article explains the problem and solutions - https://medium.com/netscape/hacking-it-out-when-cors-wont-let-you-be-great-35f6206cc646

Answer (score 0):

Basically browsers do not allow requesting another domains content unless the server allows it. But another server should be able to.

An angular application isn't enough to achieve this on its own. What you can do is proxy those calls using your own local server, for example *Nodejs* with *express* which would host the application too, or set the Allowed-Origin headers to allow requests from your app.

You would then make requests to your server with the URL of the page you want to inspect, your server would GET that URL and download the HTML and then return it in a response back to you.